# Split keys (12-13-14) of a dict and find lowest number

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, split

What loop can I build to split the following two keys from dictionary "x", and assign the lowest value to a string?

`x.keys()`

```
['12-13-14', '1-2-3']
```

The output should be the following **string**:

```
['12', '1']
```

I know I probably need `.split("-")`, but I don't know how to write the loop to do this.

Comment: Your output **string** isn’t a string.

Comment: Yes, it’s a list of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No loop needed; just use a list comprehension.

```
>>> keys = ['12-13-14', '1-2-3']
>>> [str(min(int(x) for x in key.split('-'))) for key in keys]
['12', '1']
```

What this does: for each `key` in `keys`, it splits the key by `-` using `split('-')`, just as you thought, and converts those to `int` (because `2 < 12`, but `'2' > '12'`), finds the `min` of those, and convert back to `str`.

Or even shorter (and much more concise), as suggested by @poke:

```
>>> [min(key.split('-'), key=int) for key in keys]
```

This does not convert to `int` and back to `str`, but instead uses `int` as the `key` function by which to determine the minimum.

Comment: Shorter version: `[min(key.split('-'), key=int) for key in keys]`

Comment: thanks! it works perfect. sometimes a challenges on when to use a loop or just code like this above.